# String Comparison Loop issues

Tags: c, string, loops, comparison

I'm making a little text adventure game in C for fun, and I have run into a little issue.

```
char cobra_weapon[5];
int cobra_sword_bonus = 3;
int cobra_mace_bonus = -2;
int cobra_attack_score;
int cobra_main_hand;
int cobra_off_hand = shield;



do {
    fgets(cobra_weapon, 5, stdin);

    if (strcmp(cobra_weapon,"sword") == 0)
        cobra_main_hand = sword + cobra_sword_bonus;
    else if (strcmp(cobra_weapon,"mace") == 0)
        cobra_main_hand = mace + cobra_mace_bonus;
    else
        printf ("You entered %s. Please enter either sword or mace.\n", cobra_weapon);
} while (strcmp(cobra_weapon,"sword") != 0 || strcmp(cobra_weapon,"mace") != 0);
```

The issue I'm running into is that the strcmp is not catching the condition when i enter the correct strings. Even if I type sword or mace, it still continues to loop. I'm sure it will be something simple that I'm not seeing, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `fgets` might take in the newline character as well, so that `sword` is really `sword\n\0`

Comment: You don't need the check in the while loop and the if statements if you add a break within the if.

Comment: I think that you can make use of a debugger

Comment: Just use strncmp instead of strcmp and only compare the length of the string you are trying to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a few things to consider:

```
char cobra_weapon[5];
```

This is not enough memory to store "sword\0".  Change it to:

```
char cobra_weapon[6];
```

...or even better, change it to a much larger dimension:

```
char cobra_Weapon[63+1];
```

Then, also change:

```
fgets(cobra_weapon, 5, stdin);
```

to:

```
fgets(cobra_weapon, sizeof(cobra_weapon), stdin);
```

And finally, remember that fgets() likes to append the '\n' character to the input string.  Hence, it is important to remove the newline.  Perhaps something like this would be better:

```
do {
   char *cp;

   while(NULL == fgets(cobra_weapon, sizeof(cobra_weapon), stdin))
      /* LOOP */ ; 

   cp=strchr(cobra_weapon, '\n');
   if(cp)
      *cp='\0';

   ...
```

---

To keep looping as long as there is a sword, -or- a mace:

```
while (strcmp(cobra_weapon,"sword") != 0 || strcmp(cobra_weapon,"mace") != 0);
```

or:

```
while(strcmp(cobra_weapon,"sword") || strcmp(cobra_weapon,"mace"));
```

---

To keep looping as long as there is -no- sword -and- -no- mace:

```
while(strcmp(cobra_weapon,"sword") && strcmp(cobra_weapon,"mace"));
```

---

To keep looping as long as there is both a sword -and- a mace:

```
while(0 == strcmp(cobra_weapon,"sword") && 0 == strcmp(cobra_weapon,"mace"));
```

---

To keep looping as long as there is a sword -or- a mace:

```
while(0 == strcmp(cobra_weapon,"sword") || 0 == strcmp(cobra_weapon,"mace"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char cobra_weapon[5];
...
fgets(cobra_weapon, 5, stdin);
```

You need 6 chars for "sword" (remember trailling `'\0'`)

Change to:

```
char cobra_weapon[6];
```

also remove the trailing `\n` when using `fgets`:

```
char cobra_weapon[6];
char *p;
...
fgets(cobra_weapon, sizeof(cobra_weapon), stdin);
if ((p = strchr(cobra_weapon, '\n')) != NULL) { 
    *p = '\0'; /* remove newline */
}
...
```

Comment: Pretty sure fgets will preserve the `\n` when the user hits enter.  So you need 7-chars:  `sword + \n + \0`.

Comment: @abelenky, The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, **until n-1 bytes are read**, or a <newline> is read and transferred to s

Comment: Yup:  That is it:  if a newline is ***read and tranferred***, then there is a newline `\n` in the resulting buffer.

Comment: @abelenky, no, `if sizeof(cobra_weapon) == 6` and you type "sword" the newline is not transfered. [ideone](http://ideone.com/j2rzx7)

Comment: and what if you type in `"mace"`? (4 chars)... then `cobra_weapon` will be `"mace\n\0"` (6 chars), which will NOT compare against `"mace\0"` successfully.

Comment: @abelenky, see my code in the answer, I'm removing the trailing newline, there is no problem with "sword" nor "mace" using `char[6]`

Answer (score 0):

you are using `fgets` to get input, which preserves the newline (`\n`) when you press enter.

As a result, for a 4-letter word, like "mace", you need to reserve at least 6 spaces:

```
mace + \n + \0
  4  +  1 +  1 == 6.
```

That is also why your `strcmp` is failing.  Trying to compare "mace" against "mace\n" will not result in a match.  They are not the same string!

Comment: No, you need only 5 chars for "mace" (and 6 for "sword") because `fgets`stops on n-1, of course you need `char[6]` and skip `\n` for  store and compare both strings, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to break out of the loop after you successfully get either `sword` or `mace`, then in addition to the other comments on increasing cobra_weapon length by 1, you can simply use `break`:

```
char cobra_weapon[6];
...

do {
    fgets(cobra_weapon, sizeof (cobra_weapon), stdin);

    if (strcmp(cobra_weapon,"sword") == 0) {
        cobra_main_hand = sword + cobra_sword_bonus;
        break;
    }
    else if (strcmp(cobra_weapon,"mace") == 0) {
        cobra_main_hand = mace + cobra_mace_bonus;
        break;
    }
    else
        printf ("You entered %s. Please enter either sword or mace.\n", cobra_weapon);
} while (strcmp(cobra_weapon,"sword") != 0 || strcmp(cobra_weapon,"mace") != 0);
```